# Disambiguating grammar for Dyck language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Given the following simple grammar for a language that contains all strings with matched parentheses:
\begin{align}
&s \to ss \\
&s \to (s) \\
&s \to ()
\end{align}

Examples: $(), ()(), (()), \ldots$

Is it possible and how to disambiguate this grammar?

Comment: A language of balanced parentheses is called a Dyck language; there's a Wikipedia page, among other introductory texts. Any introduction to Dyck languages will include the unambiguous grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your language is very similar to the [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language), the only difference being that the Dyck language usually contains the empty string.

Here is an unambiguous grammar for your language:
$$
 S \to (S)S \mid (S) \mid ()S \mid()
$$
In order to check that it generates the correct language, and unambiguously, let us consider a slightly different description of this language, replacing $($ with $\nearrow$ and $)$ with $\searrow$.
We can think of a word over the alphabet $\{\nearrow,\searrow\}$ as corresponding to a path which starts at the origin and then "follows the arrows". Your language contains all non-empty words which do not dip below the X axis and end at the X axis.

It is easy to prove by induction that all words generated by the grammar are of this form. In the other direction, suppose that $w$ is a word in your language. It necessarily starts with $\nearrow$. Consider the first time that the path corresponding to your work returns to the X axis. This breaks your word into the general form $\nearrow x \searrow y$, where each of $x,y$ is either in your language or empty. A short case analysis shows that one of the productions allows you to generate your word.

The grammar is unambiguous since the partition $\nearrow x \searrow y$ is unique: every word in your language can be put in this form in a unique way. Indeed, the prefix $\nearrow x \searrow$ signals the first time that the walk returns to the X axis. Therefore the algorithm above gives the *unique* way to construct the word with the grammar.

Comment: Can you please suggest a book to read more about Formal languages (including Dyck language and other)? I have read "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" by Michael Sipser. It does not contain any material about Dyck language.

Comment: You can try Jeffery Shallit’s A second course in formal languages and automata theory.